# Clean up CSV based on another CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, libreoffice-calc, merge, google-docs

I have a csv file named `master.csv`, which has the following columns

```
link, name
```

And another csv file called `details.csv`, which has the following columns

```
link, name, price, desc
```

I want to match `master.csv` against `details.csv` and delete the rows from `master.csv` which already have details in `details.csv`. `link` column is the unique column that matches both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Excel you can do like this, the manual way:

1. Open `details.csv`.
2. Open `master.csv`, copy all content and paste it below the last line in `details.csv`.
3. Close `master.csv`.
4. Select **Remove Duplicates**, mark only **Column A** and press OK. Now the duplicate rows should be removed from the lower part of the document (originating from `master.csv`).
5. Remove the rows in the upper part of the document, that originated from `details.csv`.
6. Save the file as `master.csv`.

If you have some requirements that it should be done programmatically, in another program or about the output of the operation, please provide that information.

Comment: This should work. As of now, I have no need to do the same programmatically.

Comment: Great to hear and I'm glad I could help! Actually it's my first answer that gets accepted :-)